# Как задать расстояние между QTableWidget и QScrollBar

Tags: python, pyqt5, qss, qtablewidget, qscrollbar

Как задать расстояние между `QTableWidget` и `QScrollBar`? 
Возможно его нужно как-то стилизовать через `setStyleSheet`?

Я смотрел в документации *PyQt5* и в таблице стилей, но ничего не нашёл.  Также не видел чтобы кто-то затрагивал данную тему на форумах.

Хочу чтобы по итогу таблица выглядела таким образом :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код :

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(400, 400)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ffffff;")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("QTableWidget {\n"
"    selection-background-color: #cccccc;\n"
"    selection-color: #000000;\n"
"    gridline-color: #000000;\n"
"}\n"
"QHeaderView::section {\n"
"    background-color: #f2f2f2;\n"
"    border-style: none;\n"
"    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;\n"
"    border-right: 1px solid #000000;\n"
"}\n"
"QTableWidget QTableCornerButton::section {\n"
"    background-color: #f2f2f2;\n"
"    border: 1px solid #000000;\n"
"}\n"
"QHeaderView::section:horizontal\n"
"{\n"
"    border-top: 1px solid #000000;\n"
"}\n"
"QHeaderView::section:vertical\n"
"{\n"
"    border-left: 1px solid #000000;\n"
"}\n"
"QTableWidget {\n"
"    border: 0px solid ;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar:horizontal {\n"
"    border-radius: 10;\n"
"    border: 2px solid #3d3d3d;\n"
"    background: #595959;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::handle:horizontal {\n"
"    border-radius: 8;\n"
"    background: #ffffff;\n"
"    min-width: 20px;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal, QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal {\n"
"    border: none;\n"
"    background: none;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::add-page:horizontal, QScrollBar::sub-page:horizontal{\n"
"    background: none;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar:vertical {\n"
"    border-radius: 10;\n"
"    border: 2px solid #3d3d3d;\n"
"    background: #595959;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::handle:vertical {\n"
"    border-radius: 8;\n"
"    background: #ffffff;\n"
"    min-width: 20px;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::add-line:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {\n"
"    border: none;\n"
"    background: none;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical{\n"
"    background: none;\n"
"}")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 370, 370))
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(10)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(10)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Window1 = MainWindow()
    Window1.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скопируйте и запустите мой пример, а потом аккуратненько установите свои стили.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(400, 400)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
#        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 370, 370))

        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(10)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(10)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.tableWidget.resize(1100, 400)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)        
        
        self.scroll_area = QScrollArea(self)                                               # 2
        self.scroll_area.setWidget(self.tableWidget)  
        self.scroll_area.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.scroll_area.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        self.scrollbar = QScrollBar(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.scrollbar.setMaximum(self.scroll_area.horizontalScrollBar().maximum())        
        self.scrollbar.valueChanged.connect(self.sync_func_horizontal) 

        self.scrollbarV = QScrollBar(Qt.Vertical, self)
        self.scrollbarV.setMaximum(self.scroll_area.verticalScrollBar().maximum())        
        self.scrollbarV.valueChanged.connect(self.sync_func_vertical)          
   
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.scroll_area, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.scrollbar, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.scrollbarV, 0, 1)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.scrollbar.setMaximum(self.scroll_area.horizontalScrollBar().maximum())
        self.scrollbarV.setMaximum(self.scroll_area.verticalScrollBar().maximum())    

    def sync_func_horizontal(self):
        self.scroll_area.horizontalScrollBar().setValue(self.scrollbar.value())

    def sync_func_vertical(self):
        self.scroll_area.verticalScrollBar().setValue(self.scrollbarV.value())
      
        
stylesheet = """
QScrollBar:horizontal {
    height: 15px;                    
    margin: 3px 15px 3px 15px;
    border: 1px transparent #2A2929;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: yellow;    
}
QScrollBar::handle:horizontal {
    background-color: blue;
    min-width: 25px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal {
    margin: 0px 3px 0px 3px;
    border-image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/right_arrow_disabled.png);
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: right;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal {
    margin: 0px 3px 0px 3px;
    border-image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/left_arrow_disabled.png);
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: left;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal:hover,QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal:on {
    border-image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/right_arrow.png);
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: right;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal:hover, QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal:on {
    border-image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/left_arrow.png);
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: left;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::up-arrow:horizontal, QScrollBar::down-arrow:horizontal {
    background: none;
}
QScrollBar::add-page:horizontal, QScrollBar::sub-page:horizontal {
    background: none;
}
 
QScrollBar:vertical {
    background-color: #2A2929;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 15px 3px 15px 3px;
    border: 1px transparent #2A2929;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
    background-color: #FF5F5F;     
    min-height: 25px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {
    margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
    border-image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/up_arrow_disabled.png);
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: top;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {
    margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
    border-image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/down_arrow_disabled.png);
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: bottom;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:hover,QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:on {
    border-image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/up_arrow.png);
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: top;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:hover, QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:on {
    border-image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/down_arrow.png);
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: bottom;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical, QScrollBar::down-arrow:vertical {
    background: none;
}
QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical {
    background: none;
}
"""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    w.resize(365, 310)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А есть ли более простой способ решение ?

Comment: @assert это и есть самый простой способ решения того что вы хотите сделать, как я понимаю вашу задачу.